# sed escaping error for a Jenkins build

Tags: sed, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to use sed to replace a line in a json file. Here is the original;

`sed -i 's/"development": "s3://dev.server.com/pentlands/atg"/"development": "new-bucket-here"/g' file.txt`

I have tried this;

`sed -i 's/"development": "s3://dev\.server\.com/pentlands/atg"/"development": "new-bucket-here"/g' file.txt`

Here is the error;

`WorkflowScript: 37: unexpected char: '\' @ line 37, column 47.
   -i 's/"development": "s3://dev\./server`

Answer (score 0):

The best way to update json file is to use a json parser like `jq`.

However if you want to perform a simple string change, you can try this:

```
sed -i 's,"development": "s3://dev\.server\.com/pentlands/atg","development": "new-bucket-here",g' file.txt
```

Note the `,` replaces the `/` and is used as separator in the `sed` command.

Comment: That didn't work, thanks anyway. I only need one line in a bash command so I don't want to install jq just for that if I can aviod it

Comment: Is there any error message?  or is the file not changed?

Comment: I doubt this is a `sed` error... please provide more information